# preg_replace: replace everything but

Tags: php, preg-replace, character

I want to remove some unwanted characters from the following string.
Here's the code.

```
 $input="aecąßÄ1,.!?-_'\"/><";  
    $input=preg_replace('/[^\p{P}\p{L}\p{N}\s]*/u', '', $input);
```

The code seems to be working fine but the special characters are lost in the output.
Here's what I get.

```
   aec���1,.!?-_'"/
```

Instead of

```
 aecąßÄ1,.!?-_'"/
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Not lost, just wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on comment:

Try to use "real" characters:

```
$input=  preg_replace('/[^aecąßÄ1,.!?-_\'\"\/]/', '', $input);
```

---

last answer:

If you want to remove unwanted characters, you can remove that characters with much simpler regex:

```
$input= "aecąßÄ1,.!?-_'\"/><";
$input=  preg_replace('/[<>]/', '', $input);
```

Just put that special characters between [ ] in regex. This will works in your case.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want. I want to remove 'everything but' not 'everything like'.